# Unexpected string crash with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am fairly new to Swift development and I'm encountering a live crash that I can't figure out. Any pointers on how to even figure this one out would be appreciated because I can't reproduce the bug locally.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```swift
struct LinkItem: View {
    var content: LocalizedStringKey // This is the line crashing (SettingsView.swift:7)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(content)
    }
}
```

And the only place where I call this view is here in my `SettingsView`:

```swift
LinkItem(content: "settings.tos")
LinkItem(content: "settings.pp")
LinkItem(content: "settings.sc")
```

and in my string file I have:

```
"settings.tos" = "Terms of service";
"settings.pp" = "Privacy policy";
"settings.sc" = "Support & contact";
```

Finally here is the data from crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  SwiftUI                        0x1bde98bd0 ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 560
1  SwiftUI                        0x1be003f94 _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews() + 168
2  SwiftUI                        0x1be003fc0 @objc _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews() + 24
3  UIKitCore                      0x18b6a73d0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140
4  QuartzCore                     0x18dc0a7dc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
5  QuartzCore                     0x18dc10958 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480
6  UIKitCore                      0x18b693684 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 536
7  UIKitCore                      0x18ab69358 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1188
8  UIKitCore                      0x18ab63210 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewControllerLookForNested:] + 604
9  UIKitCore                      0x18ab65074 -[UINavigationController _performWhileIgnoringUpdateTopViewFramesToMatchScrollOffset:] + 48
10 UIKitCore                      0x18ab652f8 -[UINavigationController _performTopViewGeometryUpdates:] + 112
11 UIKitCore                      0x18ab651c4 -[UINavigationController _updateTopViewFramesToMatchScrollOffsetInViewController:contentScrollView:topLayoutType:] + 244
12 UIKitCore                      0x18ab64e14 -[UINavigationController _updateTopViewFramesForViewController:isCancelledTransition:isOrientationChange:] + 236
13 UIKitCore                      0x18ab725b8 -[UINavigationController _navigationBarChangedSize:] + 392
14 UIKitCore                      0x18a91fdf0 -[UINavigationBar _sendNavigationBarResize] + 76
15 UIKitCore                      0x18a9689d8 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS changeLayout] + 80
16 UIKitCore                      0x18a9714f8 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS navigationItemUpdatedLargeTitleDisplayMode:] + 180
17 UIKitCore                      0x18a9246b0 -[UINavigationItem setLargeTitleDisplayMode:] + 64
18 SwiftUI                        0x1bdd0cf48 UINavigationItem.update(using:environment:navController:) + 320
19 SwiftUI                        0x1bdb02d78 UIKitNavigationBridge.preferencesDidChange(_:) + 544
20 SwiftUI                        0x1bda979d0 _UIHostingView.preferencesDidChange() + 436
21 SwiftUI                        0x1bdb82e60 ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at:) + 176
22 SwiftUI                        0x1bdea3844 closure #1 in closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 960
23 SwiftUI                        0x1bdea32ac closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 576
24 SwiftUI                        0x1bde98b30 ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 400
25 SwiftUI                        0x1be003f94 _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews() + 168
26 SwiftUI                        0x1be003fc0 @objc _UIHostingView.layoutSubviews() + 24
27 UIKitCore                      0x18b6a73d0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2140
28 QuartzCore                     0x18dc0a7dc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
29 QuartzCore                     0x18dc10958 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 480
30 QuartzCore                     0x18dc1b578 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136
31 QuartzCore                     0x18db63f1c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 304
32 QuartzCore                     0x18db8dc08 CA::Transaction::commit() + 676
33 UIKitCore                      0x18b228e58 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 80
34 CoreFoundation                 0x18711c834 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
35 CoreFoundation                 0x18711bfd4 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 264
36 CoreFoundation                 0x187117250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1100
37 CoreFoundation                 0x187116adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
38 GraphicsServices               0x19109c328 GSEventRunModal + 104
39 UIKitCore                      0x18b211ae0 UIApplicationMain + 1936
40 MY APP                         0x1041b6de4 main + 7 (SettingsView.swift:7)
41 libdyld.dylib                  0x186fa0360 start + 4
```

I've then tried to change the code to pass a String, but I'm getting the exact same crash.

```swift
struct LinkItem: View {
    var content: String

    var body: some View {
        Text( NSLocalizedString(content, comment: ""))
    }
}
```

---

In the comments it was pointed it could be related to `UINavigationItem setLargeTitleDisplayMode`.

Here is what I do in the SettingsView:

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("settings.title"), displayMode: .inline)
```

In context, it's more or less:

```swift
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
      // Most content
    }..navigationBarTitle(Text("settings.title"), displayMode: .inline)
  }
}
```

In my `ContentView` I have the following things in my `init` call:

```swift
init() {
  UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
  UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: Color.appDark.uiColor(),
    .font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
  ]
}
```

Comment: No crash & localized correctly with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7

Comment: @Asperi it's the same on my end, it's working perfectly fine locally, but I'm still seeing significant crashes in production for some users

Comment: Maybe your app does not have localizations for them?

Comment: @Asperi it does display the right text in the UI, so from what I understand it should be fine on that end. If the localization is missing it would crash the app?

Comment: Should not, but it is SwiftUI - still new - everything's possible, so better to check.

Comment: @Asperi i've just purposefully set the wrong translation key and it just displays it, no crash.

Comment: The crash stack does not look like depends directly on LinkItem, but `UINavigationItem setLargeTitleDisplayMode`, ie. changing NavigationBar title. Would you show code how you manipulate with it? Do you have any customisations in the area (like using UINavigationBar, etc.)? Do you have mix UIKit/SwiftUI in the area? In short, could you provide more details about your real code?

Comment: @Asperi I've updated the question with more details, let me know if this helps

Comment: Ok, and where is used LinkItem?

Comment: @Asperi It's used 3 times within the  `// Most content` section

Comment: Can you upload a inimum reproducable project?

Comment: In my experience with SwiftUI and iOS development, Xcode tends to crash frequently on builds or runs. I personally use AppCode from JetBrains for development. I don't get any crashes using this software. But, restarting Xcode tends to do the trick most of the time. Also, you may run into issues if you are using the previews, so I recommend just running on the simulator.

Comment: this is a completely wild guess, is it the ampersand "&" ?  try just deleting it ??

Comment: Is the iOS version of the crashing device an unofficial iOS 14 beta?

Comment: If XCode command line tools are far away from actual device iOS version, it will sure crash no matter what you try. The "real" answer here is, sorry, update your machine /OS/ XCode etc. You will may have a breakdown or headache, but nothing will make your swift compiled app on older cmd tools to work on "new" iOS version existing in devices. e.g. users just updated to iOS 14 :)